# Ansible syntax error : unexpected parameter type in action: class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

```
- name: 'Partition'
  tags: ['fs', 'fs-ext4']
  vars:
    vdcnames: 'ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | grep "{{volume[items["name"]]}}" | head -1 | cut -d "/" -f 1'
  tasks:
    - name: 'Get vdcnames value'
      shell:
        cmd: '{{ vdcnames }}'
      register: 'vdcnames_out'
    - name: 'Resizing the partition'
      shell:
        cmd: >
          sgdisk -e {{ items.device | d( volume[items["name"]] ) }} &&
          parted -m -s -a opt {{ items.device | d( vdcnames_out.stdout ) }} resizepart 1 100%
  when:
    - 'not items.skipped | d(False)'
    - 'items["drive"]["name"] | d("") == "trwer"'
    - 'items["partitions"] | d([]) | count == 1'
  loop: '{{ volumes.results }}'
  loop_control:
    label: '{{ items.name }}'
```

Above code is in roles/abc/main.yml. I was getting the below error for the above code

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

The error appears to be in '/roles/abc/main.yml': line 20, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:
- name: 'Partition'
  ^ here
```

I modified the code for resolving the syntax issue as below but still the same error

```
- name: 'Partition'
  tags: ['fs', 'fs-ext4']
  vars:
    vdcnames: 'ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | grep "{{volume[items["name"]]}}" | head -1 | cut -d "/" -f 1'
  tasks:
    - name: 'Get vdcnames value'
      shell:
        cmd: '{{ vdcnames }}'
      register: 'vdcnames_out'
      loop: '{{ volumes.results }}'
      loop_control:
        label: '{{ items.name }}'
      when:
        - 'not items.skipped | d(False)'
        - 'items["drive"]["name"] | d("") == "trwer"'
        - 'items["partitions"] | d([]) | count == 1'
    
    - name: 'Resizing the partition'
      shell: |
        sgdisk -e {{ items.device | d( volume[items["name"]] ) }} &&
        parted -m -s -a opt {{ items.device | d( vdcnames_out.stdout ) }} resizepart 1 100%
      loop: '{{ volumes.results }}'
      loop_control:
        label: '{{ items.name }}'
```

I was trying to resize the disk through ansible but facing this error. Can someone please help me what's exactly the error is?
I tried a lot for resolving this by modifying the code but error is still the same, not sure why.

Comment: There should not be a `tasks` dictionary in a role tasks file.

Comment: There is an example of role tasks file in the documentation, here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Then how should I declare both tasks 'Get vdcnames value' & 'Resizing the partition'.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε As both tasks are dependent on each other and also loop and loop_control needed for both tasks

Comment: Look at the documentation I pointed to? The task file should be a simple list of tasks, but is not under a `tasks` dictionary.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I can see Role directory structure in the link.   
Do you mean to say that I should remove **-name: 'Partititon'** and broke task under tasks dictionary into 2 seperate tasks?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254861/discussion-between-007-programmer-and---).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this helps. But, since Ansible 2.0 there is resizefs option in the filesystem module that is false by default and that supports ext4.

If yes, if the block device and filesystem size differ, grow the filesystem into the space. Supported for ext2, ext3, ext4, ext4dev, f2fs, lvm, xfs, vfat, swap filesystems.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/filesystem_module.html

```
- name: 'Extend the FS'
  filesystem:
    fstype: 'ext4'
    dev: '/dev/sda1'
    resizefs: yes
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I have to think in generic perspective as I have many disk and servers on which this ansible code has to run.